# Amazon Ec2 segfault error

Tags: java

I have a production Java application hosted on Jetty. During the last week or so, the system has crashed, leaving only a single message accessed with "dmesg":

java[20551]: segfault at 000000004315dd78 rip 00002aae428a018d rsp 000000004315dd60 error 6

Can anyone point me in the correct direction as to what this means ?

Answer (score 0):

Are your `javac`and `java` the same version? This is usually the problem when you get this error.

You can get the versions  like this:
`which -a java` and `which -a javac`

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The path and version is /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_18. Once if we get the segfault error the jetty server goes down, so how to fix this? Please suggest.It causing a lot of problem.

Comment: But are both the same version?

Comment: Yes both are the same version below i mentioned: # java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
# javac -version
javac 1.6.0_18

Comment: # which -a java
/usr/bin/java
/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/java

# which -a javac
/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/javac